# Environment specific config files - best practices?

Tags: java, deployment, configuration, jakarta-ee

I have an application with a configuration file which has a lots of environment-specific settings. Also I have a bunch of environments where that application can be deployed.

What are the best practices of making that configuration environment-specific?

Currently I'm adding the directory where the config files are located to the JVM classpath. This way application simply loads the configuration files from the classpath and uses what it finds there.

However, recently I was told that this is a bad practice and that I should consider using JNDI for such purpose.

So, what could you recommend to make the deployment and development processes as painless as possible in my situation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could allow users to specify the configuration file/directory with whichever of the following appeals to you: (1) a command-line argument; (2) a Java system property; or (3) an environment variable.

Note that you can access the `FOO_CONFIG` environment variable by calling `System.getenv("FOO_CONFIG")`. Sun "deprecated" (a euphemism for deliberately broke) this operation between Java 1.0.1 and Java 1.4.x inclusive. However, this operation was undeprecated (that is, fixed) in Java 5.

Answer (score 1):

You could set up and maintain specific sets of config files per each environment, in distinct folders under your project root. Then you could extend your build process with a parameter to determine which environment to build for, so that it can copy the required config files into the package to deploy. The deployed app then sees the config files always in the same place, and it has only one consistent set of files, minimizing the chance of errors.

The drawback of this approach is potentially lots of duplication between your config sets. This can be solved by generating the concrete config files as part of the build process. Extract all variable config parameters into distinct config property files, one per each environment, and create a template config file set, which contains placeholder names instead if the real parameters in every applicable place. Then all you need is a preprocessor in your build which creates a set of config files from the temples, replacing the placeholders with the corresponding concrete values. (E.g. Maven has built-in support for *properties* and *profiles*, and also for generating resources at build time.)

Comment: Well, the problem is, each environment is managed by a different set of people. In our office we are programming the code, then building a deployment package. That package will then be run somewhere else (we do not need to care where). So it would be great to have some independent documented configuration file that can be configured separately on each environment without any additional hassle.

Comment: Just an addition: usually we do not even know the configuration settings that are used on each enironment due to security issues.

Comment: @Max, I see. So the creation of environment specific configurations is actually a set of distinct projects, for which you only need to provide supporting infrastructure. Using the classpath is brittle in that there may be different (even unrelated) config files in different folders on the classpath. I would probably just nominate one specific directory for the config files, and load the config explicitly from there. Well documented template/sample config files are also essential to help others create their own configs.

Comment: @Péter Török: There we go with another problem. Various environments have different OSes. That is, we can't decide to use "/configs" as some Windows PC could have no "/configs". Also we can't do a check for OS because some machine could have no "C:" disk either...

Comment: @Max, you should use relative paths, and platform specific path separators (Java does support these).

Comment: @Péter Török: Hm, relative path's sound logical but still it feels a bit messy. Usually apps get deployed to some /var/opt/../../../../../ directory and config files will reside somewhere nearby? I'd say it's creepy.

Answer (score 1):

We have similar requirement. This is how we implemented it.

We have `shared-app.war` file that is shared accross different departments. The code in this `.war` file looks for (or reads from) `shared-app-cfg.properties` file. This properties file will be different for each department.

In `.war` file's manifest we say it depends on `shared-app-cfg.jar`.
The `.war` expects `shared-app-cfg.jar` to be available in runtime environment.
The contents of this `.jar` file is `shared-app-cfg.properties`.

Each department will have to build this jar file containing properties file.
Depending on how each department builds their application they can:

1. Package `shared-app-cfg.jar` with `shared-app.war` file in an `.ear` file.
2. Alternatively, put the `.jar` file in `shared-lib`.
   Not sure if this is elegant solution... but it solves the issue.

Comment: Hello, Pavan. Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, format your posts correctly. Read [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and if you have any doubts, feel free to **contact me** at `jmendeth@gmail.com`. Thanks!

Comment: Basically your solution is very similar to storing properties in classpath-accessible property files, as it requires the configuration to reside in file-system specific place (other jar file which has always the same placement within the system). However, you gave me a nice idea to package properties into jar files, looks prettier this way :).

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, if you have lot of environment-specific information, you're better off using config files as you already do, had you had only a few strings, you could have used jndi environment strings instead.

Answer (score 0):

Another guess (awaiting comments) - is it good practice to put "/configs" string into JNDI and let application load the configs from there? Looks better than adding it to classpath and still fulfills it's purpose pretty well. What do you think?

Comment: I think it is good for production - you set up config on production server and just deploy application. But for development and testing this might be not a very handy way of doing it.